# Why does express-validator not detect missing fields when validating XML input?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-validator

I have an express-based server that parses xml rather than json (using `body-parser-xml`).

I then use `express-validator` to validate the body input like this (the real code doesn't look quite like this, but this simplified example still triggers my issue):

```
router.post("/", 
    body('session.credential[0].$.username', 'Username').isString().trim().notEmpty(),
    (req, res) => { /* check validationResult() and then continue with business logic */ });
```

If I now send something like this to the server it works (it will generate an error because `user` is not the same as `username`):

```xml
<session>
    <credential user="" />
</session>
```

But if I instead send this it will not report any error:

```xml
<session>
    <credential />
</session>
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Can you include an [mcve] that folks can run? (e.g. the minimal express code plus a curl command that submits only enough XML to show off the problem). Without that, there's no way to tell what your code actually does, because route handlers are based on middleware chains, and it's impossible to tell what that `body` function does (folks can try to guess, but guesses are not answers =)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I just tried to keep the question as lean as possible to not add irrelevant things to it. The `body` function for example would be known as a standard function in express-validator. But of course, if one does not know about that particular package I can understand the confusion. Either way, as I said in the answer I posted, this is a bug in the latest version of express-validator.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it turns out this is a bug in version 7 of express-validator: https://github.com/express-validator/express-validator/issues/1245.

I downgraded to 6.15.0 and that fixed the problem.